# Run event once during Update() XNA / C#

Tags: c#, xna

this is the best way I can think of doing this. Could you give me so hints as to whether this is the correct way or if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

My situation is:
Each time the frame is Update()'ed (Like in XNA) I want to check if something has happened.. Like if the timer for that screen has been running for over 2000 milliseconds. But I only want it to fire once, not every time the frame is updated. This would cause a problem:

```
if(totalMilliseconds > 2000)
{
    this.Fader.FadeIn();
}
```

So I came up with this method that I have implemented in the GameScreen class that looks like this:

```
public bool RunOnce(string Alias, bool IsTrue)
{
    if (!this.Bools.ContainsKey(Alias))
        this.Bools.Add(Alias, false);

    if (IsTrue && !this.Bools[Alias])
    {
        this.Bools[Alias] = true;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

This basically checks if the passed if statement boolean is true, if it is then it fires once and not again unless the Bool["Alias"] is set back to false. I use it like this:

```
if(this.RunOnce("fadeInStarted", totalMilliseconds > 2000))
{
    this.Fader.FadeIn();
}
```

This will then only run one time and I think is quite easily readable code-wise.

The reason I have posted this is for two reasons.. Firstly because I wanted to show how I have overcome the problem as it may be of some help to others who had the same problem.. And secondly to see if I have missed an obvious way of doing this without creating a manual method for it, or if it could be done more efficiently.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you didn't use a simple bool flag?

Comment: Mainly so I could save space in the code, this way on one line it creates the the bool, checks the bool each update() and only returns true once.

Comment: Save space? This doesn't look like saving space at all, not to mention this is way more confusing

Comment: You may want to take a look at System.Reactive from Microsoft (https://reactive.codeplex.com/). It allows lots of fun ways to control your code, such as throttling how often something can run. It may not apply to your case, but it seems to solve some similar problems. That being said, the way you implemented it seems okay except for the above mentioned confusion around the bool flag.

Comment: I'll check that out now, thanks. The thing with having a bunch of separate bools is that you have to define each bool at the top of your code and set them to there initial values, then within the if statement add a ' && !Bools[FadeInStarted]' and then once it's fired you would have to add another line within the if statement to turn the bool on so it doesn't fire again. I am listening to what you guys are saying though and maybe the way I'm doing it is fundamentally wrong lol..

Comment: If I understood you correctly you already have a bunch of flags so you decided to tie them up together?

Comment: The GameScreen class has a dictionary of Bools. Then within the if condition (on the extended GameScreen) the RunOnce method adds the necessary bool to the dictionary and then tests against it, plus sets it to true when the passed condition is true. For the extended GameScreen this means there is less code because you don't have to worry about defining bools and switching them on/off etc. It sounds petty when I put it like that but I just get quite fussy with how many lines I'm using, maybe too much though lol.

Comment: Well, it achieves it's goals but I wouldn't do it myself. I don't know why you prefer to do this way, but hey if it works for you why not. I'd just put all the flags in one spot under a `#region` area -> collapse them and never look at them again. No need to worry about any dictionaries or any other problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach this problem.

These are your requirements:

1. You have arbitrary pieces of logic which you want to execute inside of your `Update()`.
2. The logic in question has a predicate associated with it which determines whether the action is ready to execute.
3. The action should execute at most once.

The core concept here is "action with an associated predicate," so create a data structure which represents that concept:

```
public class ConditionalAction
{
    public ConditionalAction(Action action, Func<Boolean> predicate)
    {
        this.Action = action;
        this.Predicate = predicate;
    }
    public Action Action { get; private set; }
    public Func<Boolean> Predicate { get; private set; }
}
```

So now, your example becomes

```
var action = new ConditionalAction(
    () => this.Fader.FadeIn(), 
    () => totalMilliseconds > 2000);
```

In your `Update()` you need something that can execute these conditional actions:

```
public void Update(GameTime time)
{
    // for each conditional action that hasn't run yet:
    //     check the action's predicate
    //     if true:
    //         execute action
    //         remove action from list of pending actions
}
```

Because their predicates are probably unrelated, actions don't necessarily run in order.  So this isn't a simple queue of actions.  It's a list of actions from which actions can be removed in arbitrary order.

I'm going to implement this as a linked list in order to demonstrate the concept, but that's probably not the best way to implement this in production code.  Linked lists allocate memory on the managed heap, which is generally something to be avoided in XNA.  However, coming up with a better data structure for this purpose is an exercise best left for another day.

```
private readonly LinkedList<ConditionalAction> pendingConditionalActions = 
    new LinkedList<ConditionalAction>();

public void Update(GameTime time)
{
    for (var current = pendingConditionalActions.First; current != null; current = current.Next)
    {
        if (current.Value.Predicate())
        {
            current.Value.Action();
            pendingConditionalActions.Remove(current);
        }
    }
}

public void RegisterConditionalAction(ConditionalAction action)
{
    pendingConditionalActions.AddLast(action);
}
```

Registered actions will wait until their predicates become true, at which point they will be executed and removed from the list of pending actions, ensuring that they only run once.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is interesting, I don't see a problem with it, you've essentially created a new programming construct.

I haven't encountered this situation a lot so what I have done in this situation is always start with the untidy approach:

```
bool _hasFadedIn = false;
```

.

```
if(totalMilliseconds > 2000 && !_hasFadedIn)
{
    this.Fader.FadeIn();
    _hasFadedIn = true;
}
```

And 90% of the time I leave it like that. I only change things if the class starts growing too big. What I would do then is this:

```
_faderControl.Update(totalMilliseconds);
```

Put the logic for fader control into a separate class, so:

```
class FaderControl
{
   bool _hasFadedIn=false;
   public void Update(int totalMilliseconds)
   {
       if (_hasFadedIn)
            return;
       if (totalMilliseconds <= 2000)
            return;
       this.Fader.FadeIn();
       _hasFadedIn=true;
   }
}
```

It can be modified to make it configurable, like reseting, setting "start", "end", fadein time, or also controlling fadeout too.